# Changing Date format in SSIS expression

Tags: sql, ssis

In SSIS, I have an expression that goes:

```
"SELECT _sessions.session_id AS session_id, _sessions.user_id AS user_id,
       _sessions.updated_at FROM public._sessions _sessions
        WHERE  _sessions.updated_at  > '"  +(DT_STR, 20, 1252)@[User::MaxId] + "'"
```

This outputs:

```
SELECT _sessions.session_id AS session_id,   _sessions.user_id AS user_id, 
       _sessions.updated_at FROM public._sessions _sessions
       WHERE  _sessions.updated_at  > '13/10/2016 11:58:00'
```

However I need the date to output as so:  `> '13-10-2016 11:58:00'`. it's the dashes and not the slashes.

How do I change my expression in order to meet this?

Answer (score 3):

In SSIS, when you cast a DateTime type to string, it's calling the underlying .NET object's ToString() method. That will use your localization rules to produce the string.

You have dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss due to a UK localization. I'd have mm/dd/yyyy etc for a US locale.

Therefore, if you want a special format, you have to build it yourself. I'm using StartTime as it made it easier for testing but, assuming `MaxId` is also a datetime type, it's a simple substitution

```
(DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(@[System::StartTime]) 
+ "-" 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH(@[System::StartTime]),2) 
+ "-" 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(@[System::StartTime]),2)
+ " "
+ LEFT(RIGHT((DT_WSTR, 24) (@[System::StartTime]), 11), 9)
```

The thing to note above is that to get the leading zero for day and month, we prepend a leading zero to the emitted string (for the month of March, we'll have 03, for October, it will be 010) and then only preserve the trailing 2 characters. This is much cleaner to troubleshoot than conditional logic based on the actual date.

I take a lazy route for time manipulation so I use the last 11 characters of the default time cast to get the time portion but then strip the AM/PM modifier off the end of that.

Answer (score 1):

You have SSIS non-standard format for date DD-MM-YYYY. Try this expression

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("dd", @[User::MaxId]), 2) + "-" + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("mm", @[User::MaxId]), 2) + "-" + 
(DT_STR, 4, 1252)DATEPART("yyyy", @[User::MaxId]) +  
+ " " + (DT_STR, 8, 1252)(DT_DBTIME)@[User::MaxId]
```

This builds your date. Second line adds time part.